# Spring Boot unable to communicate with MySQL DB in docker environment

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, microservices

I am trying to run a springboot microservice docker image. It fetches the DB connection properties from a Config server. However it is unable to connect to the container.

**Error :**

```
JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

**Exception :**

```
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar!/:8.0.21]
Caused by :
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
2020-09-28 11:39:32.782 [ : ] WARN  [task-1] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
 1 --- [         task-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
2020-09-28 11:39:32.791 [ : ] ERROR [task-1] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
 1 --- [         task-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

**Properties located at Config Server**

```
shopping-service.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://A.B.C.D:3306/shoppingCartDB
shopping-service.datasource.username: root
shopping-service.datasource.password: root
```

`A.B.C.D` is my docker host IP.

**application.yaml**

```
datasource:
    url: ${shopping-service.datasource.url}
    username: ${shopping-service.datasource.username}
    password: ${shopping-service.datasource.password}
    #driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
        show_sql: true
        ddl-auto: create-drop
  profiles:
    active: dev
```

I have pulled the MySQL 8.0 docker image from docker hub.

```
docker pull mysql/mysql-server:8.0
docker run --name=mysql-container -d mysql/mysql-server:8.0
```

Changed the password to "root".

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

Created the database :

```
mysql> create DATABASE shoppingCartDB;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
```

**Docker RUN**

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 shoppingms:latest --env shopping-service.configserverurl=http://A.B.C.D:8888 --env shopping-service.eureka.url=http://A.B.C.D:4444/eureka
```

It is able to fetch the properties from config server. I checked the logs. Error came from this line :

```
 com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
```

In my local environment I am able to use the locally installed MySQL Db with the same connection parameters. However in docker I am getting the exceptions. Where I am going wrong can anyone please help me out.

**UPDATE :**

After exposing the MySQL container to port 3306, the error stands at now :

```
2020-09-28 12:07:43.942 [ : ] WARN  [task-1] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : null,  message from server: "Host 'Some-IP' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
     1 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : null,  message from server: "Host 'Some-IP' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

2020-09-28 12:07:49.219 [ : ] WARN  [task-1] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1130, SQLState: HY000
 1 --- [         task-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1130, SQLState: HY000
2020-09-28 12:07:49.225 [ : ] ERROR [task-1] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - null,  message from server: "Host 'Some-IP' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
 1 --- [         task-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : null,  message from server: "Host 'Some-IP' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
```

Comment: You should expose port. `docker run -p 3306:3306 --name=mysql-container -d mysql/mysql-server:8.0`

Comment: @omer : Okk let me try once.

Comment: Are you running your app in a container along side the MySql container and wanting them to communicate internally?

Comment: @user626201 : Yes isnot that posisble, or do I have to create a docker network first for communicating.

Comment: @Som it depends on your docker networking topology, but, yes you can get them to communicate internally via docker DNS and yes, you would generally need to configure the docker networking if you have multiple apps, otherwise the general docker network should be ok

Comment: you may want to try using `docker-compose` when running multiple servers (eg. java web server + mysql server) https://dev.to/scottshipp/docker-compose-a-spring-boot-app-backed-by-mysql-89m

Comment: @omer ; After exposing the container explicitely to port 3306, that error seems gone. But a new error came. Updated my question.

Comment: @Som I suspect this is from your root user config. For docker `localhost` is `localhost` for the container, not for the host. So `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';` will configure root user for the `localhost` on the container. You would need to `ALTER USER 'root'@'SOME-IP (host IP)' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';` to connect from the host into the container

Comment: Yes I identified the ip address from docker inspect and changed the password. But some additional steps are required. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to resolve the issue now.

```
 1. Identify the ip address from docker inspect command.
 2. Create an user for that ip.
 3. Need to alter the new user password.
 4. Grant some privileges to the user.
 5. Exit
```

Now run your container again, this time it could obtain the connections and successfully create the tables.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest running a docker compose file to describe your application setup.

As a guide line, this is a compose file for running phpMyAdmin, MySQL 8, tomcat on a given network. I have given a guess at your application requirement:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  # Update the below for your application
  app:
    image: shoppingms:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    links:
      - db:db
    environment: 
      - shopping-service.configserverurl=http://A.B.C.D:8888
      - shopping-service.eureka.url=http://A.B.C.D:4444/eureka
    networks: 
      - appnet
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    ports:
        - 3306:3306
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
        MYSQL_USER: user
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: user123
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: user123
    volumes:
        - ./sql-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
        - appnet
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    links:
        - db:db
    ports:
        - 8201:80
    environment:
        MYSQL_USER: user
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: user123
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: user123
    networks:
        - appnet
  tomcat:
    image: library/tomcat:9
    restart: always
    links:
        - db:db
    ports:
        - 8081:8080
    volumes:
      - ./tomcat/webapps:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps
      - ./tomcat/logs:/usr/local/tomcat/logs
    networks:
        - appnet

networks:
  appnet:
    name: appnet
```

In this application I was running a externally hosted tomcat server with Spring webapp volumed into the container. There are various ports exposed as well for ease of external access.

You would need configure/tweak your application container as per your requirement.

The Database is exposed on the DNS name `db` which is what phpMyAdmin uses.